# Django model inheritance data saving in both models

Tags: django, inheritance

I am trying to use the Django admin to allow rudimentary management of page menus. I have one principal menu which I decided to extend with a sub menu to allow drop downs where necessary. Because the submenu item would have the same fields as the main menu items I though it would be a good idea to use inheritance and so the sub menu would inherit all the fields from main menu as well as having a foreign key relationship like so:

```
# main menu
class MainMenu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField()     

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Main Menu Items" 

# submenu - for drop downs
class SubMenu(MainMenu):
    main_menu = models.ForeignKey(MainMenu, related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Sub Menu Items"
```

I register the models with the admin, but when I save an item in the submenu, not only does it go into the sub menu it makes the **same entry** in the Main Menu. Any ides what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to somehow tell Django that I inherit the methods of MainMenu without saving to it? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But that's how model inheritance works. SubMenu has an implicit OneToOne relationship with MainMenu, but the "inherited" fields actually belong to MainMenu.

What you could do is to define a BaseMenu abstract model - use `abstract = True` in the inner Meta class. Now both MainMenu and SubMenu inherit from that, but SubMenu adds its `main_menu` link.

Comment: yeps, that's how inheritance works in django. So you have to choose what suits best for you: inheritance or foreign key. Using both of them just doesn't make sense

Comment: I thought I would save some time by avoiding making a base class, but it was actually very quick. This is definitely the way to do it. Thanks for all the helpful input!